# Using select case with order by fetch next 1 rows does not work when null records

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have script for Oracle Database 11G. However, the case statement returns null as no record when running it alone until "DESC" but when I include the FETCH NEXT 1 ROWS it says that I am missing right parenthesis even the number of () are correct.
But when I removed the Order By clause it works. The problem is that in reality there could be more than 1 records or none. In this case, there is no record, it is null.

```
 select distinct (tb1.ID) as "EMP_ID",    
       (case when (tb2.col2 = 5) THEN TO_CHAR(tb2.dateFrom, 'YYYYMMDD') 
             ELSE (SELECT tb3
                   where tb1.ID = '12145' and
                        tb3.col3 = (select ID from tb4 where tb4.ID = 25)
                   ORDER BY tb3.dateFrom DESC
                   FETCH NEXT 1 ROWS ONLY
                  )
      ) END AS "POINTS"    
 from Table1 tb1 join
      Table2 tb2 
      on tb1.ID = tb2.ID    
 where tb1.col1 = '1'
```

results in:

```
Error: 
ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis
00907. 00000 -  "missing right parenthesis"
```

Comment: 11g doesn't support `fetch next`.  You have multiple other errors and logic issues.  I would suggest that you delete this question, ask another question with sample data, desired results, and an explanation of what you want to do.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the logic issues and multiple errors.